# How to preload images through Code Snippets wp_head for specific pages?

Tags: performance, wp-head

## Circumstances:

#### Website Structure

My Wordpress website is used as presentation and portfolio for my graphic design services. **Visual impact is important** for me, so most of my pages contain big background hero image as first impresions and/or entrance animations.

#### Languages

Is relevant to share that all of the pages have two versions: one for english and one for spanish. It matters because **I'm trying to preload specific images for both versions** of a page (example: Contact page in english and Contact page in spanish both contain the same images)

#### Relevant Plugin for the topic

**Code Snippets** is the plugin I'll be using to add the preload tag to the headers.

**WebP Converter for Media** is the plugin I use for compression, replacing files in standard JPEG, and PNG formats with WebP format.

## The problem:

Even though I serve static Cached versions of the website and use a compression plugin to minify the images weight, the very first images of each page load on the go (for example: in the middle of the entrance animation) and ruins a big part of the experience.

[Here you can see](https://www.simbiontecreativo.com/contact-simbionte-designer/) one of my website's pages to understand what I mean.

## The solution I'm aiming for:

I need to preload those "first impression" images by adding a `<link>` tag using `rel="preload"`, specifying the URLs for each of those images. The tag **should only be added to the page that uses those images**.

## The code:

**I know nothing of PHP**, so the following code might have several rookie mistakes because it's a copy-paste of different articles I've found.

(the code is meant to be inside a **CodeSnippets** snippet, aiming for the Contact page in spanish and english, with IDs equal to 5135 and 2061 respectivly)

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'preload_page_contact' );
    function preload_page_contact(){
        if(is_single( array( 5135, 2061 )) {  ?>
            <link rel="preload" as="image" href="image1URLhere.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"/>
            <link rel="preload" as="image" href="image2URLhere.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"/>
            <link rel="preload" as="image" href="image3URLhere.webp" media="(min-width: 768px)"/>
        <?php  }
    };
<?php } );
```

As far as I know the following code targets a specific page with ID=5135

```
if(is_single( '5135' )) {  ?>
```

But I need to target both english and spanish version. So I read that the following array returns true if it matches one or the other:

```
if(is_single( array( 5135, 2061 )) {  ?>
```

It doesn't work. It states that "e" is undefined. So I'm probably missing something.

---

**An extra question** I've got concerning this very topic is the following:

Should I use the URL of the original image (PNG/JPG) or the URL of the compressed (WEBP)?

Comment: Are you working with Post or Pages? The context of your question indicates you are working on pages, which is_single is directed to posts. I would recommend reviewing the three related WordPress Conditional Tags [ is_single vs. is_singular vs. is_page]